# Find the conjugacy classes of $(123), (132) \in S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

> Find the conjugacy classes of $(123), (132) \in S_3$.

I could work out for {e} and [(12)]={(12),(13),(23)}. But I'm struggling to compute the conjugacy class for (123).. Can somebody point out any mistake?

- For (123)

  - $(123)^{(123)} = (123)$
  - $(123)^{(132)} = (123)$
- For (132)

  - $(132)^{(123)} = (132)$
  - $(132)^{(132)} = (132)$

So it seems that they are trivial classes...? 
** I've gone through articles on maths SE and know the answer but I found that none of them actually showed the calculation for (123)...

Comment: Did you also conjugate by other elements? There are more elements to $S_3$.

Comment: hmm, but they are in [(12)], right? so I didn't consider them in my calculation...

Comment: But the definition of the conjugacy class of $\sigma \in S_n$ is $\{x\sigma x^{-1} | x\in S_n\}$.

Comment: oh,,, that's true... Thank you!!

Comment: Have you done centralisers and orbit/stabiliser? In case, they provide another useful angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the conjugacy class of $\tau\in S_3$ is

$$\{\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\in S_3\mid  \sigma \in S_3\}.$$

> In particular, then, for example, we have the conjugacy class of $(123)$ is $$\{(123)^e, (123)^{(12)}, (123)^{(13)}, (123)^{(23)}, (123)^{(123)}, (123)^{(132)}\},$$ which is $$\{ (123), (213), (321), (132), (123), (312)\}=\{(123), (132)\} .$$

Comment: It is worth remarking that, combined with a computation for what conjugating one permutation by another permutation is, this shows that the conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are all elements of a particular “cycle type”, which is the length of the cycles when the permutation is written as a product of disjoint cycles.